# Given a nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear form, and linearly independent vectors, find a set of vectors s.t. $g\left(v_{i},w_{j}\right)=\delta_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, symmetric-functions

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$,
> $g:V\times V\to \mathbb{F}$ a symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form.
> If $v_1,\ldots ,v_k \in V$ linearly independent is a set vectors then
> $\exists w_1 ,\ldots ,w_k \in V$ s.t.
> $$g\left(v_{i},w_{j}\right)=\begin{cases} 1 & i=j\\ 0 & i\neq j
> > \end{cases}=\delta_{ij}$$

I tried using induction but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: ... oh I see ...

Comment: it is missing only positive definiteness

Comment: @janmarqz indeed, but in this case it isn't given so we can't assume it's an inner product. also, I believe the gram-schmidt process will give us $w_1 ,\ldots ,w_k$ s.t. $g(w_i , w_j ) = \delta_{ij}$ and not $g(v_i , w_j ) = \delta_{ij}$